# Blockchain streaming and the reasons for it

Tags: blockchain

So I've been seeing "blockchain streaming" or "blockchain live streaming" and such lately and I've been wondering. What is blockchain streaming, what problems does it solve and how is it any better than the normal way of doing it (file serving from the server)?

I have done a small bit of research on Blockchain and I think I got the simple part of it. It's a way to store data in blocks which are chained together with their hashes. But didn't understand how it would be better for streaming. How is it better to store video data in block(s)? There's not much of a paper I could find about blockchain streaming other than the news of websites who use this.

Also, a small thing that came to my mind was bandwidth. I think the reason we don't see a lot of "YouTube killers" is because streaming uses a lot of bandwidth and it might be expensive. So I thought maybe this had something to do with the "torrent" or "web torrent" where users are the "seeders" and there's not much of a server cost but I don't think that would have something to do with blockchain.

Answer (score -1):

You have got it but not the crux!!The crux of using blockchain technology in video streaming is using the unutilized computing power.See if you think blockchain as only blocks linked with hashes of each other then i would say the thing can be more simplified.

Like you can think of it as the same old traditional distributed P2P network of computing resources with a new set of rules called blockchain which handles the classical failures of a distributed network like Byzantine failures and Fail stop failures.You can consider blockchain as a database with set of rules to these fault prone distributed networks which prevents all components of the network from cheating and helps the whole distributed network to settle/agree on a certain state.Because it is very difficult to maintain trust and transparency in a distributed network.That is why you ended up downloading viruses in your system once you download from torrent.This is because the network hosting the file is not the stake holder of the correctness/behaviour of the file!!!.

This is where blockchain fits in.Enabling such rules so that originality/transparency remains in a vast distributed network.
Now the answer to your question is simple, if you keep your computing resources in a blockchain network then as traditional distributed networks(think of how torrent works!)you can fully leverage all your computing resources even in there idle time.Research shows that

"You've got $10 billion to $20 billion of data center assets that are doing nothing,"

So imagine if you can utilize the resource at a single time how much efficiency you can improve.You can see VideoCoin and https://sonm.com/.

Thanks!

Comment: can i know the reason for down voting?what if i can prove what i have written?